# Window Form C# TextBox no displaying return string when a button is pushed

Tags: c#, task

I have a window form application that will execute a function in another file (Voice.cs) and display result in textbox when a button is pressed.
However, it does not show the string in my text box and my application is freezed.
Could i know what bring to this issue.

This is my button in form.cs to press to execute the function

```
private void VoiceStart_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string command = Voice.RecognizeSpeechAsync().Result;
        VoiceBox.Text = command;
    }
```

This is my program code in Voice.cs to perform speech recognition:

```
class Voice
{
    public static async Task<string> RecognizeSpeechAsync()
    {
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "southeastasia");

        using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
        {
            var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
            return result.Text;

        }
    }


}
```

Do i need to adjust anything to make it display and to unfreeze my application?

[image]

Comment: You are blocking the UI thread when you call `Voice.RecognizeSpeechAsync().Result;` - Try changing it to `VoiceBox.Text = await Voice.RecognizeSpeechAsync();` (and change VoiceStart_Click_2() return type to `async void` - must be void because it's an event handler)

Comment: You should also probably change the await in the `RecognizeSpeechAsync()` method to: `var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't *mix* `await` and `Result`, make `VoiceStart_Click_2` being `async`:

```
//Side note: async void is a bad idea except event handlers
private async void VoiceStart_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string command = await Voice.RecognizeSpeechAsync();
    VoiceBox.Text = command;
}
```

Comment: `.Result` as well as `.Wait` *stops* execution (UI) until the `Task` completes and then assign the `Result`; `await` requires the compiler to implement `.ContinueWith` so UI *keeps on working*, but when the `Task` completes, the rest code (`string command = ... and VoiceBox.Text = command`) will be executed

Comment: Thank you very much!! I got the ideas